# What do you do when the only answer to your question is not as helpful as one of the comments on the question?

Tags: discussion, comments, self-answer

Here's my question: [ES6 generators- are they really an alternative to async/await?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27236960/725866)

A user posted a comment on my question that answered the question for me:

> This may help: http://davidwalsh.name/async-generators.  async/await can be
>   implemented as syntactic sugar over generators + promises

To which I replied:

> Thanks for the link- very helpful. If you want to post that as an
>   answer I'd accept it. Seems the answer to my question is yes.

In the meantime another answer has been posted.  I feel that the initial response in the comments section "answered" my question and is more helpful than the answer in the answers section.

What should I do?  Edit the answer?  Post another answer?

Comment: Don't edit the answer against an answerer's intent. You can self-answer if you want and mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, and *give credit to the person who gave you the comment*.

Comment: Now that there's a comment that answers your question, I am sooo tempted to write a useless answer to this question.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot- ha I was thinking the same thing

Comment: @Compass thank you for your response- if you'd post it as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Editing an answer should only be done to improve an answer. It should not be done to change the content of an answer, i.e. if the user recommends using an `Array`, it is wrong to edit it to say `ArrayList`. The author's intent should be maintained when an answer is edited, even if it's wrong, or not as good as the correct answer.

That's not to say that nothing should be done with the answer, even if it's not as good as the answer you found most helpful. If the answer is helpful, you do have the discretion to upvote it as a possible answer, even if it isn't the best answer.

If a comment is a link-only answer as you've posted, you should explain the answer and expand on it so that it qualifies as an answer, because link-only answers are undependable and grounds for deletion/editing.

Original comment:

> This may help: [What do you do when the only answer to your question is not as helpful as one of the comments on the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278477/2958086)

can be converted into an answer:

> The comment provided by @Compass ([What do you do when the only answer to your question is not as helpful as one of the comments on the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278477/2958086)) help solved the issue. 
>   The link points out that editing an answer that changes the author's intent is not a good course of action and instead recommends that a new self-answer be written. The self-answer should strive to be a quality answer that is not link-only, and give credit to the original comment writer.

Comment: makes sense, maybe the comment that I found helpful was not posted as an answer because it would have been considered a link-only answer.

Comment: I see what you did there (and I *like* it).